# How to take and evaluate a specific part of a list without evaluating the rest?

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation

I have a large list, for example,

```
lis = {x + y, x y, Sin[x] y + Exp[y], x^2 y}
```

and its elements depend on variables `x` and `y`. Later I assign numerical values to `x` and `y`

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
y = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

If I run

```
lis[[1]]
```

(which is `Part[lis, 1]`), the whole list `lis` will be evaluated, and then the first part is taken. But if the list is very large, and I only need the first element, it will waste lots of time to evaluate the rest. Is there a simple way to take and evaluate a specific part of a list without evaluating the rest?

Comment: This could be better example: `ClearAll[x, y, z, list];
list = {x, y, z};
x = 1;
y = 2;
z := Pause[2];`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could map `Hold` over the list:-

```
lis = {x + y, x y, Sin[x] y + Exp[y], x^2 y};
heldlis = Map[Hold, lis];
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
y = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
ReleaseHold@heldlis[[1]]
```

> {4, 6, 8, 10, 12}

Comment: This is the first thought that occurs in my mind:)

Comment: Another possibility in case `lis` is very large would be to change `heldlis = Map[Hold, lis]` to `heldlis = Hold @@ lis`, and accordingly `ReleaseHold@heldlis[[1]]` to `heldlis[[1]]`. This proves to be faster for both the creation of `heldlis` and the retrieving of the sough element from the last evaluation. It also uses less memory.

Comment: @Xavier - `heldlis = Hold @@ lis` works ok.  Then you don't need `ReleaseHold`; just `heldlis[[1]]` will suffice.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a simple way to take and evaluate a specific part of a list **without** evaluating the rest?

You could use the `Rule[]` rather than `Set[]`. For instance,

```
lis = {x + y, x y, Sin[x] y + Exp[y], x^2 y};

lis[[1]] /.{x -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, y -> {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}}
```

> ```
>  {4, 6, 8, 10, 12}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

If you define `lis` before `x` and `y` as a plain `List` you can use the following trick with `OwnValues`

```
ClearAll[x, y];
lis = {x + y, x y, Sin[x] y + Exp[y], x^2 y};
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
y = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

Part[Hold@lis /. OwnValues@lis, 1, 1]
(* {4, 6, 8, 10, 12} *)
```

Indeed, it calculates the first element only:

```
Part[Hold@lis /. OwnValues@lis, 1, 1] // Trace

(* {{{OwnValues[lis], {HoldPattern[lis] :> {x+y,x y,E^y+y Sin[x],x^2 y}}},
 Hold[lis] /. {HoldPattern[lis]:>{x+y,x y,E^y+y Sin[x],x^2 y}},
 Hold[{x+y,x y,E^y+y Sin[x],x^2 y}]},
 Hold[{x+y,x y,E^y+y Sin[x],x^2 y}][[1,1]], x+y,
 {x,{1,2,3,4,5}}, {y,{3,4,5,6,7}}, {1,2,3,4,5}+{3,4,5,6,7},
 {1+3,2+4,3+5,4+6,5+7}, {1+3,4}, {2+4,6}, {3+5,8}, {4+6,10}, {5+7,12},
 {4,6,8,10,12}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to store each part of the list using memorization and then call the part you want.

```
Quit[];

i = 1; (f[i++] = #) & /@ (lis = {x + y, If[x > 0, Pause[5]], 
    Sin[x] y + Exp[y], x^2 y});
```

Now try this and check the difference in time.

```
x = 1;
f[1];
lis[[1]];
```